# Trouble updating to Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

I am trying to update to Angular 6 from 5.2. I use yarn and have updated angular cli both local and global to latest version. I have node 8.

When I run any of the following commands:

ng update @angular/core

ng update @angular/material

ng update

Absolutely nothing happens...just starts a new line in the terminal.
Why is this happening, and what do I need to do update to Angular 6?

Comment: Cool, thanks you for sharing. What is the actual question?

Comment: How can I successfully update to Angular 6 using ng update, why is ng update not working for me

Comment: Did you update @angular/cli ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without more information, it's mostly just troubleshooting steps, but I have also provided some workarounds you could try.

1. Try using the `ng` `--dry-run` option to see what the cli is attempting to do.
2. Check your intended version of `@angular/cli` installed correctly

   - Reinstall with `yarn global add @angular/cli@latest` or
   - `npm install @angular/cli@latest -g`).
3. It might be an issue in your dev environment (check installations/folders/path of `yarn`, `npm`, `node`)
4. Check your project artefacts to see if anything has partially migrated/changed (`.angular-cli.json -> angular.json`)

**Hopefully these troubleshooting steps should resolve most issues, but I have elaborated based on my experiences below.**

## Additional steps

If your `@angular/cli` did update correctly as you say `@angular/cli` (verify your global and local packages folder because sometimes a misconfiguration with `yarn` can break things. *I had some breaking experiences with my npm and yarn setup when migrating an Angular 2 project to 6, which I do not recommend*)

Do you get any error messages on

```
yarn global add @angular/cli    # npm install -g @angular/cli
yarn add @angular/cli           # npm install @angular/cli
ng update @angular/cli
```

Check if you now have an `angular.json` (replaces `.angular-cli.json` in Angular 6)

Once those things are resolved, you may have to install `rxjs-compat` as well (I had to for one of my other nested dependencies) for backwards compatibility even after updating your project source files `import`s.

#### Edit:

In direct response to your question here:

> When I run any of the following commands:
>
> ng update @angular/core
>
> ng update @angular/material
>
> ng update
>
> Absolutely nothing happens...just starts a new line in the terminal.
>   Why is this happening, and what do I need to do update to Angular 6?

As a bit of a workaround, you could try manually running yarn or npm to update the dependencies instead of relying on `ng` cli.

```
npm install @angular/animations@latest @angular/common@latest @angular/compiler@latest @angular/core@latest @angular/forms@latest @angular/http@latest @angular/platform-browser@latest @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@latest @angular/platform-server@latest @angular/router@latest --save

npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular@latest @angular/compiler-cli@latest @angular/language-service --save-dev
```

References for more info:

- https://medium.com/@jeroenouw/upgrade-to-angular-6-4520e46c682b
- https://blog.angular.io/version-6-of-angular-now-available-cc56b0efa7a4
- https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/update
- **Interactive tool for each version migration of Angular** https://update.angular.io/